# Replacing ampersand in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How do i replace ampersand in a string with `&amp;`?

```
DECLARE
l_string VARCHAR2(1000):='AB&CD';
BEGIN
    SELECT REPLACE(l_string,'&','&\amp;') INTO l_string FROM dual;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('l_string = ' || l_string);
END;
```

Comment: What's the goal here? If you're generating HTML or XML from plain text, the `&` symbol isn't the only thing to care about.

Comment: Need to temporarily replace & to create xml from the string

Comment: Your code [works](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a7d1e61dc2176fc91940dfcfbc0a06ab). So what is the problem?

Comment: when i run it , i get a prompt asking for value of CD and when i do not enter any value and run it, CD is lost. I am running this on SQL developer

Comment: Execute `set define off` before running that code.

Comment: This code is inside a stored procedure . Cannot use set define off.

Comment: So you get prompted when you compile it, not when you run it. Two different things. Set define off before compiling it.

Answer (score 1):

encode

```
select dbms_xmlgen.convert('"ab&cd < ef"') from dual;
```

and decode

```
select dbms_xmlgen.convert('&quot;ab&amp;cd &lt; ef&quot;',1) from dual;
```